# Retrieve data from php

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have a small piece of code that makes a connection with a webpage. When I login Iretrieve the user_id from the database and put that in a textbox. 
Then I want to retrieve the Firstname and Lastname from the database but when I do that I get a `<br/>` from the webpage. I cannot find out why I get the `<br/>` instead of the firstname.

This is my php code to handle the request that I get from Java

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user'];
$voornaam = $con->select('voornaam', 'users', 'id', $user_id);
$achternaam = $con->select('achternaam', 'users', 'id', $user_id);

echo $voornaam;

public function select($detail, $table, $row, $value) {
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connect, "SELECT `$detail` FROM `$table` WHERE `$row` = '$value'");
    $associate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $associate[$detail];
}
```

And this is the code that I use to send the data to php

```
public static String Select() {
    String mysql_type = "2"; // 2 = Select

    try {
        String urlParameters = "mysql_type=" + mysql_type;
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HTTP_Connection/index.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();

        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null)
        {
            return line;
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();

        return reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException iox) {
        iox.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why I get the `<br/>` instead of the first name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Note :** Your `public function select()` function returns the array, not a variable. so you can't do this, `echo $voornaam;`

Comment: @Ranjith How can i solve this issue then?

Comment: Replace `echo $voornaam;` into `print_r($voornaam);`. Update the result with your question.

Comment: @Ranjith I still get the <br/> instead of my $voornaam

Comment: Lets trace your bug where you stuck? It may outside of the function or inside the function. Use `echo` and `print_r()`

Comment: Its not in the select function, in PHP i still get my $voornaam but when i pass it to Java i get the <br/>

Comment: So i still have the problem and tried your suggestions, do you have another idea how i can solve it

Comment: @Ranjith I still have the problem but i don't get the <br /> anymore, i now get a empty line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that in the line where you select the $voornaam: 
`"SELECT`$detail`FROM`$table`WHERE`$row`= '$value'"`

You use 3 different quotes:
U use ", ', 
`Try to replace the`with ' and then I think it should work.

So replace 
`"SELECT`$detail`FROM`$table`WHERE`$row`= '$value'"`
with `"SELECT '$detail' FROM '$table' WHERE '$row' = '$value'"`